# Allure and Citrus test framework

Tags: allure, citrus-framework

Can Allure also be used or integrated with the Citrus test framework, mainly in order to get a nicer test result report?

If yes, are there examples for it?

Answer (score 0):

As Citrus tests are nothing but JUnit or TestNG tests and Allure seems to have good integration for those frameworks you should succeed in combining Citrus and Allure, too. I think you can follow the instructions here:

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/TestNG

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/JUnit

Please make sure to execute the Citrus tests then with surefire Maven plugin.

Comment: Ok, I will see how that works out. I hoped there would be an example. For instance it is obviously a question how to mix Citrus behavior driven steps with Allure's different way of defining them. Anyway, I will see how good these two things really fit together if I try myself.